# I can't call the data properly into my html page

Tags: html, sql, django, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pull data from the SQL Table that I have and I am able to create a for loop for the number of items i have in the table but i am unable to pull the data.

main.py

```
@app.route("/Playback" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Playback():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `movies`")
    query = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('playback.html', cursor=cursor, query=query)
```

playback.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Movie Name:</td>
        <td>View</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    {% block content %}
    {% for obj in query %}
    <tr>
        <td><p>{{ cursor['movie_name'] }}</p></td>
        <td><button>View</button></td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</table>
```

Here is what I have tried and the results are in the picture below
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p18I0.png)

i am trying to pull the movie name from the table movies but the movie names from the table is not appearing. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a small mistake in your template when accessing the movie name within the loop. You are using cursor['movie_name'], but it should be obj['movie_name'] because you are iterating over query and each item in the loop is assigned to the variable obj.
try this instead

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Movie Name:</td>
        <td>View</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    {% block content %}
    {% for obj in query %}
    <tr>
        <td><p>{{ obj['movie_name'] }}</p></td>
        <td><button>View</button></td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</table>
```

Now I guess it should display the movie names correctly